# Boost.Move integration with other Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, rvalue-reference

*Rvalue* references generally boost performance in a C++ program. But they are not available directly in a C++03 compiler. Fortunately `boost::move` seems to be able to emulate it even in C++03:

> Rvalue references are a major C++0x feature, enabling move semantics
>   for C++ values. However, we don't need C++0x compilers to take
>   advantage of move semanatics. Boost.Move emulates C++0x move semantics
>   in C++03 compilers and allows writing portable code that works
>   optimally in C++03 and C++0x compilers.

Things like the standard library written with C++98/03 will not benefit from `boost::move` as they need to be re-written. (New versions of the standard library like VC10's have been re-written using rvalue references.)

But I am wondering how many Boost libraries have been re-written since `boost::move` was introduced in 1.48?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the [Boost version history](http://www.boost.org/users/history/), I see that **Unordered** was updated in 1.48 and **Thread** was updated in 1.50. I can't see any others that have adopted Boost.Move.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any report say how much VC11/VC10 version of STL efficiency has been increased because of re-written in c++ 11?

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked Boost 1.51.0 and it seems that `boost::move` is supported by the following libraries:

- Container (including `vector`, `list`, `map` etc.)
- Interprocess (including `smart_ptr` and `unique_ptr`)
- Intrusive
- Thread
- Unordered

Just search for `BOOST_RV_REF` in Boost headers which is a sign of `boost::move` support.